# SharedPreferences within each item of ListView

Tags: android

Get on the example:

I have two items in my ListView:

```
Item 1

Item 2
```

Within each item has a calculator that stores the result. Where:

```
Item 1 = 0

Item 2 = 0
```

On the calculator which is in `item 1`, I add `20` or any other number that I want to add, and then the `item 1` will store the resultador to min, with SharedPreferences.

Now as I want the `item 1` and `item 2` are:

```
Item 1 = 20

Item 2 = 0
```

But in reality they are as follows:

```
Item 1 = 20

Item 2 = 20
```

In short, I added only for `Item 1` the value `20`, `Item 2` is `20` also and that I did not add anything to `Item 2` only to `Item 1`, I wanted when I add the value in `Item 1` he kept, and other values continue `0`.

Click code:

```
         @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {

                Valor valor = valorAdapter.getItem(position);

                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putSerializable("valor", valor);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetalheValorActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Within each item:

```
    private static EditText edit;
    private static Button plus;
    private static TextView textView;
    private static float valor = 0;
    public SharedPreferences save;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalhe_valor);

        edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        save = getSharedPreferences("save",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        valor = save.getFloat("valor", 0);

        textView.setText(Float.toString(valor));


     plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String counter = edit.getText().toString();

            if (counter.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Write a value to add!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                 //se você não colocar nada no checkbox
                //vai dizer para digitar um valor númerico
            } else {
                float counterAsFloat = Float.parseFloat(counter);

                    valor = valor + counterAsFloat;
                    textView.setText(Float.toString(valor));
            }

        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        editor = save.edit();
        editor.putFloat("valor", valor);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

That hope you can understand.

Comment: I understand there's a problem with your code, but obviously it's difficult to imagine where without seeing it ;)

Comment: I post my code, thank you @rupps

Comment: I don't understand very well what's going on, however it looks like you always read/store the value in the same preferences field ("valor"), so when it comes to assign the value to the 2nd item, apparently the last stored value in "valor" is read.May that be the casE?

Comment: Yes, it is more or less that I want to put a key for each list item created by the User. @rupps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is in your code. Check getView in your adapter. the problem is tha getView returns the same view every time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code getView on the adapter how to i do that ? @QArea

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resource, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Valor valor = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.textNome.setText(valor.getNome());
        viewHolder.textDesc.setText(valor.getTexto());


        return convertView;
    }
```